# Add ALT tag to Image automatically

Tags: 2013, image

The WCAG (Web Content Accessibility Guidelines) provide a baseline for accessibility standards so various tools, such as screen readers, can provide a reasonable experience for those with accessibility challenges.

With regards to images, the guideline provides that all Image tabs  should probably (I say probably here for various reasons) have an ALT tag.

Is there any product/ .wsp file/ any custom solution that will add ALT tag to image.

Answer (score 2):

Add your own UserCustomAction ScriptLink (use the SharePoint Editor Chrome Extension)

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img){
  if(!img.hasAttribute('alt')){
    img.setAttribute('alt','This is an IMG which did not have an alt attribute')
  }
});
```

https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor